# Collision Frequency in Liquids

Tags: electrochemistry

I’m trying to quantify the current produced due to electrolysis of an electrolytic solution.

What physical model can I use to determine the mean velocity of each ion species in my solution, taking into account collisional effects in the liquid?

My scenario involves producing an electric field across an aqueous ionic solution. How can I quantify the current produced in the liquid, as well as determining the power dissipated due to resistance? Moreover, is Ohm’s law an applicable model?

Comment: Why can't you measure the voltage and current and calculate power consumption?  The drift velocity of ionic species is something that carries little relevance, and you can get power from $P=IV$

Comment: I am trying to quantify the relation between I and V to begin with. All the parameters I know of are ion density and electric field strength, but I need to know collisional effects to model it as a resistor.

Comment: It sounds like you need to measure the conductivity (or resistance) across your electrodes.  Then, you should be able to use the relationship $I=V/R$